# Select TreePanel node by ID

Tags: extjs4

In ExtJS 4.1 I'm selecting a TreePanel node by its ID like this:

```
var n = myTreePanel.getStore().getNodeById(id);
myTreePanel.selectPath(n.getPath());
```

.. which seems like a lot of typing for such a simple operation.  Is there a more concise way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe there's a more concise way of writing that code that's built-in to the framework. You can always just write your own method and add it to the Tree class.

```
Ext.tree.Panel.addMembers({
    selectPathById: function(id){
        var me = this,
            node = me.getStore().getNodeById(id);
        if(node){
            me.selectPath(node.getPath());
        }
    }
});

/* Later, in your own code */
myTreePanel.selectPathById(id);
```